# How to upload all the files from local to host using Curl?

Tags: unix, shell, script, curl, upload

i have written a shell script to upload all files with different names in the specific path from local to host, but i have facing some issue and the files are not getting uploaded

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /main/folder1/path/*
do
curl -u Pass:"Uname" -T  $file http://www.example.com/folder/$file
done
```

please help me to solve this.

i am getting the error as following

```
<html>
<head>
<title> 500 Internal Server Error </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> 
Internal Server Error 
</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

currently i am having the script inside `/main/folder_2`, if i change `/main/folder_1/path/*` to `../folder_1/path/*`, i got the output, the files are moved as expected. but i want to run the script with the complete path specified.

Comment: you use `file` as var, then `$i` later, is that a typo ?

Comment: yes, by mistake i typed '$i' here it is '$file' only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would change you script like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in /folder/path/*
do
  curl -u username:password -T ${file} http://www.example.com/folder/${file}
done
```

Note that the for-loop variable `file` is used with `curl`.

Better way is to upload using `find + curl` (as was [answered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14020013/1832863)):

```
find /folder/path/ -name '*' -type f -exec curl -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -T {} http://www.example.com/folder/ \;
```

P.S. More info about

> some issue is stopping the files getting uploaded

would be helpful.

Comment: hi dude, thanks for the help, this one worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad [it](http://superuser.com/a/941561/156832) helped.